# Error while installing package with pip

Tags: python, pip, google-drive-api

I want to install and use [PyDrive](https://github.com/googledrive/PyDrive) package with pip. I have python2.7 and python3.4 in my ubuntu.
I tried to install by `sudo pip install PyDrive`, It has been installed successfully. But when I use this package in a file:

> from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

I get error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myfile.py", line 1, in <module>
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
ImportError: No module named pydrive.auth
```

PyDrive and other packages codes are located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages`, and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` is empty.

Comment: I advice you to install [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for Python 2.7.x (3.4 has a built-in `pyvenv` which is almost identical).

Comment: Try using `pip2` instead, or create a virtualenv.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `pip2` if you wish to have it for python 2. I think that the default `pip` works for the latest version (so if you have python3 and python2, `pip` will work for the latest which is python3).

To install it on ArchLinux: `sudo pacman python2-pip`